# How can I cancel a Paypal [v2] order?

Tags: paypal

We use the Paypal's v2 API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/.

I would like to cancel/destroy the order which have *CREATED* status and the payment older than 10 minutes.

Do you have any Idea?
I tried to call /v2/checkout/orders/{token} with DELETE method, but this method do not available.

Answer (score 0):

Orders are valid for 72 hours once created by API, and 3 hours if the customer loads the checkout/begins an approval flow.  Orders cannot be cancelled.

If they no longer interest you after 10 minutes, simply forget about the order, and do not capture it.

Comment: It is not a good solution because on my application logic dont allow two opened payment.
If the user pay for both, it would be bad operation.
The user can save the token and this is the worst case.

Comment: Your server has control over what it captures, that is all there is to it